# Blur/focus not working as expected in Opera

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, cross-browser, opera, onblur

I am using the following jquery code to make textbox's border orange on focus and gray on blur.
Also while performing the validation if the input for a particular textbox is incorrect the border becomes red and a 'X' (which is a label) is displayed.

```
$(function() {

    $('.textbox').focus(function() {
        $(this).css('border', '1px solid orange');

    });
    $('.textbox').blur(function() {
        $(this).css('border', '1px solid gray');
    });

    // $('.num').mouseover(function() {
    //  $('.num').easyTooltip();
    //  });

    $("label").easyTooltip();
    // $("a").easyTooltip();


    $('.checkdate1').blur(function() {
        var checkdate = $(this).val();
        var error = this.id;
        error = "#lbl" + error.substring(3);
        if (checkdate != "") {
            if (isDate(checkdate)) {
                $(error).css('display', 'none');
                $(this).css('border', '1px solid gray');
            }

            else {
                $(this).focus();
                $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
                $(error).css('display', 'inline');

                 }

        }
        else {
            $(error).css('display', 'none');
            $(this).css('border', '1px solid gray');
        }
    });
 });
```

The problem is it works fine in chrome , mozilla ie onfocus orange , onblur gray and onerror red.
I set focus to textbox if input is incorrect and with red border that means if user tries to click on another textbox he wont be able to do that.
In opera , the problem appears ,, if input is incorrect textbox becomes red ,,, and has focus ,,,but if the user clicks on some other textbox ,, its color becomes orange ,,,, with focus still with textbox with wrong input.
Could anyone suggest me where is the problem
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one with the jQuery version 1.7.1. I've change some part of your code and added a function to validate the date.

```
$(function() {

    $('.textbox').on({
        focus : function() {
            $(this).css({border : '10px solid orange'});
        },

        blur : function() {
            $(this).css({border : '10px solid gray'});
        }
    });

    // $('.num').mouseover(function() {
    //  $('.num').easyTooltip();
    //  });

    //$("label").easyTooltip();
    // $("a").easyTooltip();


    $('.checkdate1').on('blur', function() {
        var self = $(this),
            checkdate = self.val(),
            new_d = new Date(checkdate),
            error = "#lbl" + $(this).attr("id").substring(3);

        if (checkdate !== "") {

            if ( dt_check(checkdate) ) {
                $(error).css('display', 'none');
                self.css('border', '1px solid gray');
            }

            else {
                self.focus().css('border', '1px solid red');
                $(error).css('display', 'inline');
            }

        } else {
            $(error).css('display', 'none');
            self.css('border', '1px solid gray');
        }
    });
 });

function dt_check(input) {

    //Date format should be (DD/MM/YYYY)

    var valid_regx = /^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/,
        returnval = false

    if ( ! valid_regx.test(input) ) {
        returnval = false;
    } else{

        var spl_date = input.split("/"),
            d_day = spl_date[0],
            d_month = spl_date[1],
            d_year = spl_date[2],
            d_obj = new Date(d_year, d_month-1, d_day);

            if ((d_obj.getDate()!=d_day)||(d_obj.getMonth()+1!=d_month)||(d_obj.getFullYear()!=d_year)) {
                returnval = false;
            }
            else { returnval = true; }
        }
    return returnval
}
```

You can disable the other field/btns to avoid entering a wrong value like this:

```
$('.checkdate1').on('blur', function() {
        var self = $(this),
            checkdate = self.val(),
            new_d = new Date(checkdate),
            other_input = $('.textbox'),
            error = "#lbl" + $(this).attr("id").substring(3);

        if (checkdate !== "") {

            if ( dt_check(checkdate) ) {
                $(error).css('display', 'none');
                self.css('border', '1px solid gray');
                other_input.attr('disabled', false);
            }

            else {
                self.focus().css('border', '1px solid red');
                $(error).css('display', 'inline');
                other_input.attr('disabled', true);
            }

        } else {
            $(error).css('display', 'none');
            self.css('border', '1px solid gray');
            other_input.attr('disabled', false);
        }
    });
```

Comment: how to get jquery version 1.7.1 ,,, is this the latest jquery library

Comment: You can download Jquery 1.7.1 from this site: http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery

Comment: OR you can use google API like this https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: @Jay ,, i tried your solution but opera seems to be the problem ,,, however i altered it and removed self.focus().css() ,,, just to stop annoying the user as not leaving the textbox could be irritating. working all right now ,,, thanks mate !!

Comment: Please let me know what is the exact issue with Opra? It should work.

Comment: @Jay ,,, the thing is when you enter some incorrect data in a textbox ,,, what we are doing is setting focus to that textbox and making border color red. That means we are not allowing the user to focus elsewhere unless he clears the input or he enters correct input.. This is working well in mozilla,,chrome,IE , in opera if i enter wrong input ,,, it gets red and has the focus ,all well .but when i click on other textbox they become orange , eventhough the focus is with the textbox with wrong input..I hope i explained it alright

Comment: @Jay ,,, thanks for your interest ,, will try this one ..thanks